# How to override CSS according to screen width

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

Below i have written some css to ensure my "sections" use up the whole screen when navigated to, however when the browser window is made smaller or accessed on mobile the content is lost as it does not fit.

I have made a media query to counter the first bit of css but I'm not sure what to set it as to counter it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px){
section.full {height: auto;}
section.contactfull {height: auto; margin-top:0%;}

}

section.full {height: 100vh;}
section.contactfull { 
height: 70vh;

margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Vertical CSS height is tricky to get, as on a phone, the height of the page is the entire page, not the viewport. Are you able to show us visually what's happening, and what you want to happen?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Lee Here is a screenshot of it working correctly at an appropriate resolution http://prntscr.com/9ab9jy And here it is breaking at a smaller resoloution http://prntscr.com/9ab9jy. What i want is for the media query to reverse the css which makes it fit the whole section to the screen.

Comment: @Lee I'm sorry here it is http://prntscr.com/9abbxf

Comment: @Lee: _“as on a phone, the height of the page is the entire page, not the viewport”_ – huh? No idea what you mean by that – mobile browsers implement the viewport concept the same way as desktop browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to leave things flow down. No matter what device people use, you can restrict only one of the 2 dimensions, but not both of them.

**Just adjust things horizontally and let them flow vertically**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the section to take up the whole screen, you can use the following:

```
section {
  display: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

I think the reason `vh` is failing you is because at a smaller resolution, the horizontal scroll bar shows up on your page, and `vh` doesn't take it into account.